# code igniter form validation returns false even if data is entered

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am setting new rules to my form, and even if the form fields are not empty, I still get stuck into the validation check block

**validation function:**

```
    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $this->input->post('action') === "add_category") {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->input->post('cat_name'), 'Category Name', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            echo "false";
            exit;
         }
         else {
                echo "true" ; exit;
            }
        }
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [action] => add_category
    [cat_name_] => gbddbd
    [parent_cat] => 1
    [cat_status] => 1
)
false
```

I creating simple `HTML` forms in my view, not with the help of `CI form helpers`

Comment: did you load the form_validation library?

Comment: @Vickel yes i did `$this->load->library('form_validation');` at the beginning of my function

Comment: your set_rules() should be set_rules('cat_name','Category Name', 'required')

Comment: yeah it worked, kindly add your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a mistake in how you use `set_rules()`

the correct way would be:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_name','Category Name', 'required')
```

**explanation:** the first parameter of set_rules() indicates the name of the input field you are validating. In your code, you are trying to assign the value of the input field, instead of the name

Answer (score 0):

You are setting rule for "cat_name" and the form field is "cat_name_" so it is failing. Change your form field name to "cat_name"

Comment: my form field is `cat_name`, i did not get u

Comment: See this Array it has cat_name_ concentrate on _ this is what you are getting in the post and you rule set for cat_name
Array
(
    [action] => add_category
    [cat_name_] => gbddbd
    [parent_cat] => 1
    [cat_status] => 1
)

Comment: yeah, then i need to ask why it is doing so? i mean my input is like
`<input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Name"  name= "cat_name " required="true" />`

Comment: there was a space in, corrected that and still have this problem

Comment: After removing the space what is your print_r($_POST) says?